# Display custom values on x axis using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have written following code to display chart. I haven't mentioned x Axis and y axis labels. Those are auto generated. 
[image]

I want to display 'low' on starting of scale and 'high' at end of scale on x axis instead of full scale.

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        },
        id: 'my_y',
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#F33',
        min:0,
        max:100
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        color: '#F33'   
    }]
});
```

Comment: what you want to show in xaxis, scale values low and high

Comment: Are you wanting to replace the 0-10 values with just low and high?

Comment: yeah, I want to display 'low' at the starting of x axis and 'high' at the end of x axis instead of the 0 to 10 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

Its a bit "hacky" i'm sure there is a better way of doing it but it works.

```
xAxis: {
     tickAmount: 2,
        labels: {   
            formatter: function () {
              if (typeof(this.axis.ticks[this.value]) != "undefined"){
                if(this.axis.ticks[this.value].isFirst) {
                    return 'low'
                }
                else if (this.axis.ticks[this.value].isLast){
                    return 'high'
                }
              }
            }      
     } 
        }
```